# Validate a field with ajax before submitting form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, validation, promise

I've just started creating a form validator, and came across a puzzling problem. If I'm validating a simple field (say, password), I can do that on the client side alone (not that I mean I won't validate it on the server). What I mean is I can do the validation on the client machine without any external checks.

If I'm validating a more complex field (username), this requires external check. For example, in a registration form, I want to validate the username (make sure it doesn't exist). To do that I'd have to make an ajax call. This complicates things a little. Examine the code below.

```
FormValidator.prototype.validate = function validateForm() {
    this.errors = {};
    for (var fieldName in this.fields) {
        var field = this.fields[fieldName];

        if (field.hasOwnProperty("required") && field.required && field.elem.value.length == 0) {
            this.addError(fieldName, "This field is required.");
            break;
        }

        if (field.hasOwnProperty("minLength") && field.elem.value.length < field.minLength) {
            this.addError(fieldName, "Input length should not be less than  " + field.minLength + " characters.");
            break;
        }

        if (field.hasOwnProperty("maxLength") && field.elem.value.length > field.maxLength) {
            this.addError(fieldName, "Input length should not be greater than" + field.maxLength + " characters.");
            break;
        }

        if (field.hasOwnProperty("ajax")) {
            // FormValidator can't possibly know what the call will return, so we can't add the error here
            // it has to be done manually
            field.ajax(this, field, fieldName);
        }
    }
    if (this.errors.length != 0) {
        // warn the user
        console.log(this.errors);
    }
};

var fv = new FormValidator(document.forms[0]);

fv.addField("login_name", {
    type      : "text",
    minLength : 4,
    maxLength : 32,
    required  : true,
    ajax      : function (fv, field, fieldName) {
        ajax("http://localhost/surec/scripts/user_check.php?field=login_name&value=" + field.elem.value, {
            success : function () {
                var response = JSON.parse(this.response);
                // manually adding the error
                if (!response.error && response.exists) {
                    fv.addError(fieldName, "This username is taken.");
                }
            },
            // async: false,
        });
    },
});

// called on form submit
// fv.validate();
```

The moment `fv.validate()` is called (assuming the user entered a taken username), `validate()` won't do anything to warn the user, because the ajax call is asynchronous. When the error check is done `if (this.errors.length != 0) {`, errors will be empty. It'll be populated when the ajax call is done, and then it's too late.

To fix this, I can make the ajax call synchronous. This solves the problem, but I'm not sure about using a synchronous call. Is this approach valid or is there an alternative approach that I can take?

---

**Update**: I've started looking into Promise, and I think I'm getting the hang of it. I've made it work to some point, so I still need some help.

Graphical depiction of what I'm trying to do would be something like this:

[image]

I've created an async loop function that I'll be using to loop the fields:

```
async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
    for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
        await callback(array[index], index, array);
    }
}
```

and the current state of the validate function:

```
FormValidator.prototype.validate = async function validateForm() {
    this.errors = {};
    var self = this;

    await asyncForEach(self.fields.keys(), async function (fieldName) {
        var field = self.fields[fieldName];

        if (field.hasOwnProperty("required") && field.required && field.elem.value.length == 0) {
            self.addError(fieldName, "This field is required.");
            // break;
        }

        if (field.hasOwnProperty("minLength") && field.elem.value.length < field.minLength) {
            self.addError(fieldName, "Input length should not be less than " + field.minLength + " characters.");
            // break;
        }

        if (field.hasOwnProperty("maxLength") && field.elem.value.length > field.maxLength) {
            self.addError(fieldName, "Input length should not be greater than " + field.maxLength + " characters.");
            // break;
        }

        if (field.hasOwnProperty("ajax")) {
            // FormValidator can't possibly know what the call will return, so we can't add the error here
            // it has to be done manually
            await field.ajax(self, field, fieldName);
        }

    });

    if (self.errors.length() != 0) {
        // warn the user
        console.log("errors: ", self.errors);
    }
};
```

This appears to work (in a test case). See below. I'm not using an ajax function, but faked it (using a 1 second delay). `console.log("errors: ", self.errors);` in `fv.validate()` runs after the external check (fake ajax) is done (1s delay).

```
var fv = new FormValidator(document.forms[0]);

fv.addField("login_name", {
    type      : "text",
    minLength : 4,
    maxLength : 32,
    required  : true,
    ajax : async function (fv, field, fieldName) {
        // assume delay is ajax
        await delay(1000);
        // and on success (and login_name collision) we add an error
        fv.addError(fieldName, "This username is taken.");
    },
});

var delay = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

fv.validate();
```

Now, I need to rewrite the external check method (`ajax`) and make it work with this code. I've tried a few combinations (probably nonsense, using trial-error), but couldn't make it work. How should I proceed?

[FormValidator.js](https://github.com/akinuri/js-lib/blob/master/FormValidator.js) (GitHub repo)

Comment: No, syncronous call is not the best approach

Comment: Don't use synchronous AJAX calls. Use `Promises` instead.

Comment: @Zenoo Although I've came across with the term `Promise` I've never used it. I've started looking into it. I'll update the question or add an answer if/when I make progress.

Answer (score 0):

Here one possible implementation with promises. It's a simplified example that just focuses on managing an array of errors where one is the result of an ajax call

```js
// errors is an array of promises
const errors = ["Too long"] 

const remoteErrorCheck = $.ajax({type:"GET", url:'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/info?site=stackoverflow'}).then(function(data){ 
    // here you have access to the result of ajax request, inside data
    return Promise.resolve("error or ok")
    // you want to return a promise to put in the array of promises
})

// now put the promise from the ajax request into the array of promises
errors.push(remoteErrorCheck)

// when all the promises are resolved, then do something with the results
Promise.all(errors).then((a)=>{
  console.log(a)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note that `Promise.all` waits for ajax to complete before executing. Strings are treated by `Promise.all` as already resolved promises.

Since `remoteErrorCheck` already has a `.then` also that one is executed and since it returns a promise, the `Promise of Promise` is squashed into just one promise, and that's why you can access the `error or ok` string in the array of errors

This needs to be adapted for your case (objects instead of strings, validation function inside the `then` should be passed from outside, ...) but it should be a good starting point

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve the problem. Instead of using a custom ajax function/lib, I've decided to use [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch).

Using it alone (without await) didn't work, so I had to add it. And now it works.

```
fv.addField("login_name", {
    type      : "text",
    minLength : 4,
    maxLength : 32,
    required  : true,
    ajax : async function (fv, field, fieldName) {
        await fetch("http://localhost/surec/scripts/user_check.php?field=login_name&value=" + field.elem.value)
        .then(function (response) {
            return response.json();
        }).then(function (response) {
            if (!response.error && response.exists) {
                fv.addError(fieldName, "This username is taken.");
            }
        });
    },
});
```

Although this works at the moment, I'm not sure if this will cause problems in the future. If it does, I'll update this QA.